# Php select (Option list)

Tags: php

I am using these codes

```
$query = "SELECT date  FROM arrival order by date" ; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die ("Error". mysqli_error($con)) ;  
echo "<select name='per1' id='per1'>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)){?>
<option value=<?php echo $row['date'];?> selected='selected'><?php echo $row['date'];?></option>
</select>
<?php
}

?>
```

The select (Option list) displays data as

```
2016-07-01
2016-07-02
2016-07-03
2016-07-04
2016-07-05
2016-07-06
and so on
```

It is not like a dropdown option list.
How to make it like dropdown list?

I want select one date from option.

Comment: You are closing your `select` in the loop instead of after it.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the `select` in the `while` multiple times. Move `</select>` outside.

```
}?> </select>
```

You also should quote the attribute value. Full example:

```
$query = "SELECT date  FROM arrival order by date" ; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die ("Error". mysqli_error($con)) ;  
echo "<select name='per1' id='per1'>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)){?>
<option value='<?php echo $row['date'];?>' selected='selected'><?php echo $row['date'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little disorganized clear it up a bit and try this

```
$query = "SELECT date  FROM arrival order by date" ; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die ("Error". mysqli_error($con)) ;

$result_array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$result_array[] = $row['date'];
}
echo "<select name='per1' id='per1'>";
foreach($result_array as $name){
echo'<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}
echo'</select>';
```

I believe that will do what you're looking for.